# Problem with Related articles PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show realted articles after each post on single.php, but got some issues with:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in". I am certain that the error is there, but i don't know how to solve it.
¿Could some one help me please? Thank you in advance.

```
...
<?php
    $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories){
        $category_ids = array();
        foreach ($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

        $args = array(
            'category__in' => $category_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array(
                $post->ID
            ) ,
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'caller_get_posts' => 1
        );

        $my_query = new wp_query($args);
        if ($my_query->have_posts()){
            echo '<h3 class="title_relatedcontent">Text:</h3><div id="related_posts"><ul>';
            while ($my_query->have_posts()){
                $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
                <div class="relatedcontent">
                <h3><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>
                </li>
            <?
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query();

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()):
        comments_template();
    endif;

endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: as you can see in this post of yours, the markdown of stackoverflow has already given you a clue about what's happening. check out the color coding of your post. you have a missing php tag right after your list html markup

Comment: Did you miss out writing PHP in <? after the end of while loop, if not it would the error.